# JSP getVariableResolver() is deprecated, what is the right way in JSP 2.2?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I use this code but is deprecated, can you help me to port it to JSP 2.2

```
   <%= pageContext.getVariableResolver().resolveVariable("varName")%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getVariableResolver%28%29), the new way of getting the variable resolver is to do `jspContext.getELContext().getELResolver()`; as a PageContext is a JspContext, you could change your line to `<%=pageContext.getELContext().getELResolver().resolveVariable("varName")`%>.

If all you want is to resolve a variable you should probably be using [EL-syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead: `${varName}`.